# AI is randomly freezing when choosing a new target (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, openai-api

I'm very new to Game Dev and have been using a combination of chat GPT and the knowledge I already have and am currently learning to build a basic game. The character that you control is running away from enemies and you have an Alli that chases and damages the enemies on contact. After damaging enemies, the Alli is coded to switch targets and it will occasionally just stop moving after destroying a current target. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FriendlyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;
    private Transform currentTarget;

    public float damageAmount = 2.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        FindInitialTarget();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (currentTarget != null)
        {
            Vector2 direction = currentTarget.position - transform.position;
            Vector2 newPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentTarget.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position = newPosition;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            // Apply damage to the enemy's health
            HealthDamage healthDamage = other.GetComponent<HealthDamage>();

            if (healthDamage != null)
            {
                healthDamage.TakeDamage(Mathf.RoundToInt(damageAmount));
            }

            // Find a new target
            FindNewTarget();
        }
    }

    private void FindInitialTarget()
    {
        GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        if (enemies.Length > 0)
        {
            float closestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
            foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
            {
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
                if (distance < closestDistance)
                {
                    closestDistance = distance;
                    currentTarget = enemy.transform;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentTarget = null;
        }
    }

    private void FindNewTarget()
    {
        GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        if (enemies.Length > 0)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
            currentTarget = enemies[randomIndex].transform; 

            Debug.Log("New Target Chosen");
        }
        else
        {
            currentTarget = null; // No enemies found
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all the troubleshooting I can think of, including using debugs to make sure the target is being updated on contact, which it is, and that my other scripts aren't interfering with the movement, which through my tests havent seem to have played any role. The Alli should be chasing and changing Enemy targets until all of them are destroyed, but it will randomly stop, but sometimes when coming into contact with an enemy while frozen will allow it to move again.

Comment: throw more debugs in, track down what it is doing

Comment: FIxed part of the issue. Just added a very slight delay to the FindNewTarget function which seemed to fix it. The targets were being chosen before the object was destroyed I think so it would choose a destroyed object and thus not have an actual target.

Comment: that sounds possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the AI might select the enemy it just collided with, thus appearing to freeze.

You could fix that by checking when selecting a new enemy:

```
do
{
    randomIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
} while (enemies[randomIndex].transform == currentTarget);
currentTarget = enemies[randomIndex].transform;
```

Comment: Yeah I beleive that was the issue. I just added a slight delay, which might not be the most optimized option haha but it allows the enemy array to update before choosing a new target.